# creating an array of object pointers C++

Tags: c++, new-operator

I want to create an array that holds pointers to many object, but I don't know in advance the number of objects  I'll hold, which means that I need to dynamically allocate memory for the array. I have thought of the next code:

```
ants = new *Ant[num_ants];
for (i=1;i<num_ants+1;i++)
{
    ants[i-1] = new Ant();
}
```

where `ants` is defined as `Ant **ants;` and `Ant` is a class.

Will it work?

Comment: @Carl Norum;I can't try it at the moment, as I'm only starting to write the code, and I still have many parts missing.

Comment: You might want to change your loop to iterate from 0 to num_ants, and assign to ants[i]. No need to offset everything by 1.

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't try it with a dummy empty class. Just create a class Foo that has nothing in it, and use the same logic.

Comment: Are you sure that the above code works? When I write the following in Visual Studio, I get a compiler error: Ant** ants = new *Ant[5];

Comment: @NMO, eventually I used a `vector` as shown in the selected answer. What is the error you get?

Comment: Syntax error: '*'. Shouldn't it be `Ant** ants = new Ant*[numants];`? I'm not a C++ expert, but I think this is a typo.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Will it work?

Yes.

However, if possible, you should use a vector:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Ant*> ants;
for (int i = 0; i < num_ants; ++i) {
    ants.push_back(new Ant());
}
```

If you have to use a dynamically allocated array then I would prefer this syntax:

```
typedef Ant* AntPtr;
AntPtr * ants = new AntPtr[num_ants];
for (int i = 0; i < num_ants; ++i) {
    ants[i] = new Ant();
}
```

But forget all that. The code still isn't any good since it requires manual memory management. To fix that you could to change your code to:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ant>> ants;
for (auto i = 0; i != num_ants; ++i) {
    ants.push_back(std::make_unique<Ant>());
}
```

And best of all would be simply this:

```
std::vector<Ant> ants(num_ants);
```

Comment: Can you really assign the result of `new` to an array?

Comment: @Mark B: Good catch. Fixed it.

Comment: So basically `new Ant* [num_ants]` is a fake call, as it doesn't call constructor at all right? Only allocates the pointer array. Thats why the `new` seems as if it is called twice.

Comment: Why "should" an std::vector be used?

Comment: It is worth noting that if Ant class is base class for other classes and instances of this derived classes also can be stored in array of Ants then the latter method (`std::vector<Ant>`) does not fit.

Comment: identifier "num_ants" is undefined?

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<Ant> ants(num_ants);
ants.resize(new_num_ants);
```

Comment: If the OP wants to use pointers to Ants, the declaration would be:  `std::vector<Ant *> ant_pointers(num_ants);`

Comment: You would also have to use `std::generate` to `new` all the respective items.

Comment: I down voted because the OP directly mentioned he wanted to use pointers, which as @ThomasMatthews mentioned, needs a different declaration. Your answer is good for a different case though.

Comment: I upvoted because OP apparently doesn't know of the array-of-objects being a better option

Answer (score 3):

Yes that's the general idea.  However, there are alternatives.  Are you sure you need an array of pointers?  An array of objects of class `Ant` may be sufficient.  The you would only need to allocate the array:

```
Ant *ants = new Ant[num_ants];
```

In general, you should prefer using `std::vector` to using an array.  A vector can grow as needed, and it will handle the memory management for you.

In the code you have posted, you would have to delete each element of `ants` in a loop, and then delete the array itself, `delete [] ant`.  Keep in mind the difference between `delete` and `delete []`.

One more point, since array indices in C++ are 0-based, the following convention is used to iterate over the elements:

```
for (i=0; i<num_ants; i++)
{
    ants[i] = new Ant();
}
```

This makes code much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to hold *pointers* to the items? If you can use objects by value, a far simpler approach is to use a vector: `std::vector<Ant> ants(num_ants);`. Then not only do you not have to write looping, but you don't have to worry about memory leaks from raw pointers and other object management items.

If you need object pointers to say satisfy an API you can still use `vector` for the outer container and allocate the objects manually.

```
struct CreateAnt
{
    Ant* operator()() const { return new Ant; }
};

std::vector<Ant*> ants(num_ants);  // Create vector with null pointers.
std::generate(ants.begin(), ants.end(), CreateAnt());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<Ant*> ants( num_ants );
for ( int i = 0; i != num_ants; ++ i ) {
    ants[i] = new Ant;
}
```

Or if you don't know how many in advance:

```
std::vector<Ant*> ants;
while ( moreAntsNeeded() ) {
    ants.push_back( new Ant );
}
```

On the other hand, I think you need to ask yourself whether
`Ant` is an entity type or a value.  If it's a value, you'll
probably want to skip the pointers and the dynamic allocation;
if it's an entity type, you'll have to consider the lifetime of
the object, and when and where it will be deleted.